# how to scroll 1 element at a time (to block free scroll)

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scrollbar

Scroll bar moves freely pixel by pixel which i don't need .What i need to do is a scroll bar scrolls the table 1 element right or left .Whatever i try schooling should not divide elements . Is it possible to make a scroll-bar that scrolls let say 200px at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `scrollBy(xnum,ynum)`

look at this

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollby.asp

**update**

using this : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/

i was partially able to do it. it kind of works with the mouse. it might be improved.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/EZpdA/

Comment: thanks looks great but this function must be triggered. i need a scroll-bar which slide like that. Is it possible to make a scroll bar to do the same

Comment: i dont think that is possible with the default scrollbar. you may need to create you own scrollbar. maybe using 'slider()' http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider